# MSBuild fails on second stage using latest Mvvmcross 3.1.1 (nuget)

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have issue when building an Mvvmcross 3.1.1 (nuget) application. I am getting this exception during second phase build (packaging the apk) on my solution

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(970,5): error MSB4018: Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006:
>   Reference to metadata item 'System.Void Android.Views.View::set_Activated(System.Boolean)' (defined in 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved.\r

This seems similar to this issue [#629](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/629). While my manifest is ok:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

I am using latest nuget Mvvmcross 3.1.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably due to the Linker on your Android project. Is Linking set on "Sdk and User Assemblies"? If yes: You need to compile with a higher Sdk version due to [this bug](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17929/error-executing-task-linkassemblies-for-android-release-build). I hope the link may help you in case you want to keep the linker like that.

Comment: But what is weird is that I am not using Latest Xamarin.Forms at all. My version is Xamarin.Android 4.12.02001

Comment: I see, it's pretty weird. I guess those bugs will be appearing on many more places than just in Forms. I hope this will be soon: "It will be fixed in the next release" (from above link). More people are experiencing issues like this one (including me).